# Not return the answer and also say in title list index out of range

Tags: selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, python-requests, webdriver, selenium-grid

Not return the Answer also say the list index out of range in title

```
url = 'https://www.adidas.com/us/women-athletic_sneakers'
driver = webdriver.Chrome('D:/chromedriver')
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(3)
time.sleep(2)

w_shoes = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('grid-item___3rAkS')
for shoe in w_shoes:
    
title = shoe.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="product-search-results"]/div[2]/div[3]/div[4]/div[1]/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/a')[0].text
print(title)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you try using requests which should fetch you the required content with the blink of an eye?

```
import requests

url = "https://www.adidas.com/api/plp/content-engine?"

params = {
    'sitePath': 'us',
    'query': 'women-athletic_sneakers'
}

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.198 Safari/537.36'
}

res = requests.get(url,params=params,headers=headers)
for item in res.json()['raw']['itemList']['items']:
    print(item['displayName'])
```

Output are like:

```
Ultraboost OG Shoes
Super Super Sleek 72 Shoes
Forum Mid Shoes
Forum Mid Shoes
Ultraboost 21 Shoes
```

Comment: https://www.adidas.com/api/plp/content-engine? where this url to get

Comment: Open dev tools by pressing `ctrl + shift + i`, select `network` tab from there and then select `All` tab. Now reload the page and find the relevant url in the left pane. Once you find it, just click on that link to get further details. Thanks.

Comment: as i find but on them is not there  price so what should i do

Comment: Please try to create another post describing your current issues. The question that you asked has already been answered. Thanks.